# Flutter , building widgets with futures, just getting a value out of the DB

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, asynchronous

So I've got a menu, and I want to simply get a single value from the db (the version ) to display...

```
        ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 0, 0),
              title: FutureBuilder<Text>(
                  future: getTextDbVersion(context),
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Text> snapshot) {
                    return snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : Text("not ready");
                  }))
```

But of course, what I'm getting is a Text widget with the text

'an instance of Future'

the method getTextDbVersion(context) , is a bit funny now as I'm trying to find my way through, but here it is.

```
  Future<Text> getTextDbVersion(context) async {
    var val = getDbVersion(context);
    print(val);
    return Text(val.toString());
  }

  Future<int> getDbVersion(context) async {
    final ContactTrackerApp app = Provider.of<ContactTrackerApp>(context);
    var storage = await app.storage;

    if (storage == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return await storage.version();
  }
```

I'm a bit new to this full async programming, and am now sure how I **just get a damn value into a string**

Any help appreciated

Comment: just curious, is the var val = getDbVersion(context); should be var val = await getDbVersion(context); ? as you are waiting the db version for printing.

Comment: I removed that getText method, was just me trying to figure things out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follows.

```
ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 0, 0),
              title: FutureBuilder<String>(
                  future: getTextDbVersion(context),
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Text> snapshot) {
                    return snapshot.hasData ? Text("${snapshot.data}") : Text("not ready");
                  }))

 Future<String> getTextDbVersion(context) async {
    var val = await getDbVersion(context);
    print(val);
    return val.toString();
  }
```

further use `initialData` parameter in future builder to show the loading status.

Comment: I get an error on the $ in that case..       Undefined name '$'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

 "message": "Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found.\nTry removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments."

Comment: sorry it is my mistake. you have to add quotation marks for `${snapshhot.data}` as "${snapshot.data}"

Comment: Can you explain why? Or link to what’s happening there?

Comment: 1. you were not await on a future of getDbVersion, therefore val.toString will just return the string as "instance of Future"

Comment: the answer was of course, just to add the await here "var val = await getDbVersion(context);" , the $ around snapshot was not involved.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are returning a widget from your `getTextDbVersion()` function. A good practice is that for the data handling methods, you should only return `Object` or primitive data types like `String`, `int`, etc. The `Text` widget should then be used later in the UI:

```dart
 Future<String> getTextDbVersion(context) async {
    var val = getDbVersion(context);
    print(val);
    return val.toString(); // Make this return a String
  }
```

In the UI:

```dart
  ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 0, 0),
              title: FutureBuilder<String>(
                  future: getTextDbVersion(context),
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Text> snapshot) {
                    return snapshot.hasData ? Text(snapshot.data) : Text("not ready");
                  }))
```

Comment: thanks , was a bit of a mess from trying to get it to work!

Comment: @MonstersX Yeah it takes a while to get used to using Stream. Btw can you choose one answer to mark as the accepted one ^^

Comment: hey! got it, although it was not anything said here, adding to question